# Firefox Extension Developer Hub - "/version" should match format "versionString"

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm developing an extension for Firefox. The last version uploaded in AMO is "1.99". Now I want to upload a new version and change the version to "2.00" in the manifest, but I get:
*"/version" should match format "versionString".*

Then I tried to change it to "2.01" and the error still exists. In a hurry, I change the version to "1.991" and it was accepted. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I found that the leading zero is a problem.
I can use version "2.1" for example.
Maybe someone will find [this Manifest Version Format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/version/format) an interesting reading.